# Java jUnit: how to assert that all objects in a list are from a certain class?

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I've built the following class:

```
public class BibliotecaApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Welcome!");
    }

    public static ArrayList<Book> getBooksList(){
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

I need to test if the method `getBooksList()`return an actual list of books.

I wrote the following test:

```
@Test
public void everyItemInTheBookListIsABookInstance() throws Exception{
    assertThat(BibliotecaApp.getBooksList(), everyItem(isA(Book.class)));
}
```

The test is passing - and it shouldn't. Note that in the actual method I return an instance of `ArrayList` (I'm practing TDD), although I defined the method signature as `ArrayList<Book>` - is that why the test passes? 
If so, how should I write a test to ensure that every item in the listem belong to a certain class (`Book`in this context)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no item in that list that isn't a `Book`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth isn't the list empty tho?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what your assertion is testing for.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sure, but I want the test to fail when the list is NOT entirely composed by Book instances. What kind of data should I return in order to achieve it so?

Comment: You should add an assertion for that.  e.g. `not(empty())`.

Comment: In  *TDD* we verify *behavior*. Your test verifies an *implementation detail* (which should not be tested) and doubles the *type check* the compiler is doing anyway. Therefore this test (as is) is useless at best.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks for the heads up! I'm just getting started. But just to make things clear, doesn't that apply more to BDD?

Comment: BDD is the nerdy new name for TDD. Conceptually it is the very same although BDD is connected with a different tooling (e.g.: JBehave)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle could provide an example of how this same test logic could be redesigned to test the behaviour? I struggle a lot to grasp the difference.

Comment: No. The reason is that TDD-Test cases derive from the *requirements*. But You did not provide any.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of `everyItem` is [documented as](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

> only matches when [...] items [...] are all matched

So an empty list will always match.

If that's a weird diea, then another way to think about it is that `everyItem` fails only if it finds an item that *doesn't* match the inner matcher.<sup>1</sup>  There are no such items in an empty list.

If you want the test to fail if there are no items at all, then you'll *also*<sup>2</sup> need to assert that explicitly:

```
assertThat(BibliotecaApp.getBooksList(), not(empty()));
```

---

<sub>1. Even if one doesn't agree on that equivalence, one can take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/Every.java#L15-L24) to see that this is indeed what's happening.</sub>

<sub>2. But you may as well drop the original assertion, because the compiler already enforces the type.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I want to assert. I want to assert if every element in my arraylist is a Book object instead.

Comment: I just want to know why the test is passing when the method in the BibliotecaApp class doesn't return an array containing books. It only returns an empty ArrayList.

Comment: @Leandro - My answer already explains that - there is no item that doesn't match the `isA()` matcher.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I just didn't understand why yet, sorry

Comment: Could you update the answer with a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Ooh, now I got it. So it works as if the "everyItem" part was never called? Since there's no items at all? I thought the "everyItem" would fail if an empty list was provided.

Comment: @Leandro - Pretty much.  Not sure if you're familiar with Java8 streams yet, but it's semantically the same as [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Comment: No, I came from Ruby and PHP. So I'm a newbie. Thanks!